opengraph-image and twitter-image - Metadata Image social previsualisation Nextjs App error
I have a Next.js Blog type application on which articles are published. Links to these are shared on social networks. I use opengraph-image and twitter-image for metadata. Initially when I do the deployment I can share 6 to 10 articles with generation of the featured image to social networks without problems in this case (LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter) and after that, the images of highlights no longer load and I end up with the fallback image that I defined.
I think it's a max memory issue for og imZages. How can I resolve the problem?
